# Yii Error: Bad Request when trying to pass an array to a controller

Tags: php, yii

I am a newbie to Yii framework. I am trying to pass an array to a controller. In my view page

```
<?php
    foreach ($simplified_list as $data) {

        echo "<tr>
            <td>" . CHtml::link($data['name'], array('view','data_list'=>$data)) . "</td>
            //<td>" . $data['data_volume'] . "</td>
            //<td>" . $data['tariff'] . "</td>
            //<td>" . $data['tariff_with_vat'] . "</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

I use **CHtml::link($data['name'], array('view','data_list'=>$data))** to pass **$simplified_list** array list to my controller. Here is my $simplified_list.

```
Array ( [success] => 1 [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => 4MB 1Day [data_volume] => 4 MB [tariff] => 2 [tariff_with_vat] => 2.3 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => 25MB 1Day [data_volume] => 25 MB [tariff] => 10 [tariff_with_vat] => 11.5 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => 100MB 7Day [data_volume] => 100 MB [tariff] => 40 [tariff_with_vat] => 46 ) [3] => Array ( [name] => 500MB 30Days [data_volume] => 500 MB [tariff] => 175 [tariff_with_vat] => 210.25 ) [4] => Array ( [name] => 1GB 30Days [data_volume] => 1024 MB [tariff] => 275 [tariff_with_vat] => 316.25 ) [5] => Array ( [name] => 2GB 30Days [data_volume] => 2048 MB [tariff] => 347 [tariff_with_vat] => 399 ) ) )
```

In my controller this is the action.

```
public function actionView($data_list) {
    $model = new User;

    $this->render('view', array(
        'model' => $model, 'data_list' => $data_list));
}
```

When I click the link it is rendered to a view page. In my view I need to access name, data_volume, tariff and tariff_with_vat records. I use following in my view.

```
<?php echo $data_list['name'];?>
```

This is the error when I try to render to the view page.

```
Bad Request

Your request is invalid.

The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. Please do not repeat        the request without modifications.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

How can I solve this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd parameter in `CHtml::link()` is url, and you passing array. Correct syntax is:

```
CHtml::link($data['name'], $this->createUrl('view',array('data_list'=>$data));
```

**Edit:**
Remove param from action:

```
public function actionView() {
    $data_list = $_GET['data_list'];
    $model = new User;

    $this->render('view', array(
        'model' => $model, 'data_list' => $data_list));
}
```

As i remember, to pass variables in action params, you must first add them to url rules.

Comment: try to remove parameter from your controller action.